# Using R package 'OSRM' to find distance and travel times between two points

Tags: r

I'm trying to find the distance and travel times between  several locations using the R package 'osrm'. I have a data frame called *coordinates* with the latitude and longitude of 32 locations in my country.

I need the distance and travel time from each point to all of the others. Therefore, the result must be a 32x32 matrix with zeros in the diagonal (since the distance and travel time from a point to itself is zero).

I used *osrmRoute* and *osrmTable*, but couldn't make it work since I got the following error message

```
distance<-osrmRoute(coordinates)
travelTime<-osrmTable(coordinates)

The OSRM server returned an error:
Error in names(loc) <- c("id", "lon", "lat"): 'names' attribute [3] must be 
the same length as the vector [2]
```

It's not clear from the documentation what the arguments of those two functions should be. It mentions a "a numeric vector of identifier, longitude and latitude (WGS84)", but I don't know what an identifier is.

Any suggestions? Solutions involving other R packages are also welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

I was capable of solving my problem after re-reading the documentation for the 'osrm' package and looking at the example provided. I added the names of the locations as a column in my data frame called *df* (so I had 3 columns: name_location, longitude and latitude). Then I used the function *osrmTable*

```
travelTime<-osrmTable(loc=df[1:32, c("name_location", "Longitude", "Latitude")], gepaf=FALSE)
```

The result is a square matrix with zeros in the diagonal and roughly symmetric. I guess it is not a symmetric matrix because going from point A to point B may take a little longer than going from B to A (maybe a road in B to A may not be available the other way around).